# WSO2 ESB Could not send the message out of ESB using clone mediator

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I have built an API to send a message to multiple REST APIs. To test it out I have mocked three REST APIs using SOAP Ui.
However I could not send the JSON message out using endpoint in the CLONE mediator.
This is a portion of the REST API Configuration:

```
            <clone id="GetOpenTasksReq">
            <target>
                <sequence>
                    <log level="full"/>
                </sequence>
                <endpoint key="OpenTask1EP"/>
            </target>
            <target>
                <sequence>
                    <log level="full"/>
                </sequence>                
                <endpoint key="OpenTask2EP"/>
            </target>
        </clone>
```

This is one of the endpoints'(OpenTask1EP) configuration:

```
<endpoint name="OpenTask1EP" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
<http method="GET" trace="enable" uri-template="http://localhost:6060/admin-service/api/getuserlists">
    <timeout>
        <duration>5000</duration>
        <responseAction>fault</responseAction>
    </timeout>
</http>
```

I have enabled enable wire logs in ESB. From the WSO2 ESB console, all I can see is the message coming to ESB from wire, the one I fired to the ESB using JMeter. On the SOAP Ui mock service I can't see the any sign of incoming request, the Message Log is empty.
Kindly advise. Please do let me know if you need more information. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try this?

```
<clone continueParent="true" sequential="true">
        <target endpoint="EP1">
             <sequence>
                    <log level="full"/>
                </sequence>  
        </target>
        <target endpoint="EP2">
             <sequence>
                    <log level="full"/>
                </sequence>  
        </target>
</clone>
```

You can give your endpoint names instead of EP1 and EP2

Comment: I have just tried something along those lines:                                                      <clone description="" id="GetOpenTasksReq">
                <target endpoint="OpenTask1EP">
                    <sequence>
                        <log level="full"/><send/>
                    </sequence>
                </target>
                <target endpoint="OpenTask2EP">
                    <sequence>
                        <log level="full"/><send/>
                    </sequence>
                </target>
            </clone>

Comment: But I have another problem. I got this error instead: "ERROR - Axis2Sender Unexpected error during sending message out
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: The system cannot infer the transport information from the /esb/api/getopentasks URL......."  I have one question regarding your suggestion, in target endpoint="EP2", does the EP2 stand for the name of a Defined Endpoints or a url?